# accumulation function in ruby doesn't work

Tags: ruby

```
def accum(start, items) 
    result, items = start, items.dup
    yield(result, items.pop) until items.empty?
    result
end

numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
puts accum(0, numbers) { |a, b| a + b }
puts accum(1, numbers) { |a, b| a * b }

# 0
# 1
```

In Ruby versions:
2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [x64-mingw32]
1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20) [i386-mingw32]

The output is

```
#0
#1
```

I would expect for all the numbers in the array to be summed and multipled.
What is the reason that the actual multiplication and summation doesn't happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never use the return value of your block, that comes out of `yield`. It should be along the lines of this:

```
result = yield(result, items.pop) until items.empty?
```

And I have to note that you're reinventing the wheel. Your accumulation function is already implemented in Ruby standard library and is called `reduce` or `inject` (either way works):

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
puts numbers.reduce {|a, b| a + b }
# But hey, we're just calling a single function with 2 args in that block
# Let's specify a symbol that corresponds to a function!
# Works pretty much the same way
puts numbers.reduce(:+)
# For multiplication too
puts numbers.reduce(:*)
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `result` to the value obtained from `yield`:

```
def accum(start, items) 
    result, items = start, items.dup
    result = yield(result, items.pop) until items.empty?
    result
end
```